Is numpy.divide a function or a class or something else?
In this code:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([2,3,4])

c = np.divide(a,b)
d = np.divide.outer(a,b)
e = np.outer(a,b)

print(f"{c=}\n{d=}\n{e=}")

It seems that numpy.divide contains outer, meanwhile numpy.divide is a function.
I’m really confused why numpy.divide behaves like both class(because it could contain something) and function(because it is callable).
print(type(np.divide)) returns <class 'numpy.ufunc'>. But why ufunc could have this effect?
My question is that: why np.divide is callable, meanwhile there is functions that is belongs to np.divide? sys.stderr.write is not a similar case as sys.stderr is not callable.

ufunc instances like divide are implemented in compiled code, so don't expect to find code that exactly matches something you could (easily) write in python (with Class, __init__, etc).  Still thinking of it as having a __call__ method along with the other documented reduce, accumulate etc methods gets you most of the way there. ufunc also share parameters like out and where.

An easy way to answer this type of question:
import numpy as np

print(type(np.divide))

Result:
<class 'numpy.ufunc'>

How can you call a class, or rather an instance of it? If a class has __call__, its instances can be called, and this ufunc is callable:
print(type(np.divide.__call__))

Result:
<class 'method-wrapper'>

It's not just that "a similar notation is used" - the instance is callable, no different from a function. A regular Python function is just an instance of the function class:
def fun():
    ...


print(type(fun))
print(type(fun.__call__))

Result:
<class 'function'>
<class 'method-wrapper'>

So, numpy.divide is both a function and an object, which is an instance of a class. If something has the type class 'something', it's not itself a class, it's an instance of that class, an object.
